# Force download of dataURI with correct filename?

Tags: javascript, firefox, download

Is there a way of forcing the latest FireFox to open a download dialog to save some local image data ([`dataURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs), [`dataURL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data%3a_URL)) with the correct filename? I want to download images.

```
window.open('data:application/x-download;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAANQAAAAAAAAAAEAAANwAAAAIAAAD+////AAAAADQAAABsAA/');
```

The above example downloads the data as `[random string].part`. [More about data: URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Embedding_an_image_via_data%3a_url). Maybe there is a way of manipulating HTTP headers  trough a faked AJAX request?

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but [this project](http://jszip.stuartk.co.uk/) came to mind, which is talking about a tool called Downloadify.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks! I think it works in that case because browsers always download zip files instead of opening them. But I want to force the download of images which are normally opened by the browsers.

Comment: @pimvdb, there is a section called "Filename problems" on the page you recommended ;-)

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding that's why they use Downloadify. Using an image filename (such as `test.png`) works on the [demo page](http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html), by the way.

Comment: Found `mozGetAsFile()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) but it does not work in FF 11 :-(

Comment: It's currently impossible, just server can suggest the file name actually.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a new HTML5 attribute for `a href` links:

```
<a href="hugemothereffinpdf.pdf" download>Download file</a>
```

Find more details [here](http://svarden.se/blog/2013-04-22-right-click-and-save-as/). I [don't know](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5600541) if that would work with the Data URI Scheme.